# How to properly align DataTable search and listbox

Tags: css, datatables

[image: This is the output i am getting after this code i want the alignment properly]I am representing some data using datatables.So in this operation i am getting the data properly and also sorting option also available but the problem is that search box and list box is not aligned properly.i am posting the code ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#metalPager').dataTable( {
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bFilter":true,
                "aoColumns": [ 
                    { "bSortable": true },              
                    { "bSortable": true },
                    { "bSortable": true },

                    { "bSortable": true }                       

                ]                   

            } );
        } );
</script>
<table width='70%' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1"
    class="metalDisplay">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Congratulations....</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
</br>
<table align="center" width='70%' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" id="metalPager">
    <thead>
    <tr>
         <th>SAPCODE</th>
        <th>FIRST NAME</th>     
        <th>LAST NAME</th>                          
        <th>STATUS</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <logic:iterate name="listOfSTPUsers" id="listOfSTPUsersId">
            <tr>
            <td><bean:write name="listOfSTPUsersId"  property="sapcode"/></td>
            <td><bean:write name="listOfSTPUsersId"  property="firstname"/></td>
            <td><bean:write name="listOfSTPUsersId"  property="lastname"/></td>             
            <td><bean:write name="listOfSTPUsersId"  property="status"/></td>
            </tr>
        </logic:iterate>
    </tbody>


</table>
```

this is the css for dataTables

```
.dataTables_wrapper { position: relative; min-height: 302px; _height: 302px; clear:  both; }
.dataTables_processing { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 50%; width: 250px;  margin-left: -125px; border: 1px solid #ddd; text-align: center; color: #999; font-size: 11px; padding: 2px 0; }
.dataTables_length { width: 40%; float: left; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; color:#70A76A; padding: 5px 0; }
.dataTables_filter { width: 50%; float: right; text-align: right; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; color:#70A76A; padding-bottom:35px; }
.dataTables_info { width: 60%; float: left; font-size:13px; color:#70A76A; padding-top:5px; }
.dataTables_paginate { width: 44px; * width: 50px;  float: right; text-align: right; padding-top:5px; }
```

this is my code .I am unable to properly align it.please help

Comment: Can anyone help me to properly align the search box and list box